# No Package chrony availiable when I install chrony

Tags: centos6, yum, ntp

In my Centos 6.5 I want to install chrony

```
# yum install chrony
```

I get the following error

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror Loading mirror speeds from cached
>   hostfile Setting up Install Process No package chrony available.
>   Error: Nothing to do

**How can I install Chrony on Centos 6.5 ?**

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your missing the `base.repo` from your install.

```
Available Packages
Name        : chrony
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.1.1
Release     : 2.el6_8
Size        : 266 k
Repo        : base
Summary     : An NTP client/server
URL         : http://chrony.tuxfamily.org
License     : GPLv2
Description : A client/server for the Network Time Protocol, this program keeps your
            : computer's clock accurate. It was specially designed to support
            : systems with intermittent internet connections, but it also works well
            : in permanently connected environments. It can use also hardware reference
            : clocks, system real-time clock or manual input as time references.
```

It sounds like you may be missing the 'CentOS-Base' repo from your config. Check in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` If it doesn't exist then create it and add the following config block;

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

You can also find the package via http://rpm.pbone.net